# Problema conversion de datos en c# a procedimiento almacenado en sql-server v2012

Tags: c#, sql-server

recurro a ustedes para que me ayuden a poder entender esto de la conversión de datos de c# a una base de datos Sql Server 2012.

Qué es lo que tengo:
Estoy trabajando con una grilla y necesito pasar esos datos por un procedimiento almacenado. Mi problema recae en que algunos de esos datos, cuando pruebo mi función, me reclama que no van en el formato específico.

Tomando eso busqué información con respecto a esto y encontré información en este [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes)

Pero aún así me siguen saliendo errores de conversión, la parte de la declaración de las variables en el procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zf_Boleta_ProcesoCalculo]
    @NumeroDoc      int         output,
    @FechaDoc       datetime    output,
    @ValorCif       decimal(18,2)   output,
    @ValorCobrar        decimal(18,2)   output,     
    @IdPeriodoProcesoDetalle int        output,
    @PeriodoProceso     char(1),   --M=Mensual ; Q=1era.Quincena ; D=2da. Quincena
    @mes            tinyint,
    @año            smallint,
    @IdCliente      int,    
    @IdTipoDoc      int,
    @IdValorizacionConcepto int,
    @IdPeriodoProceso   int,
    @CreadoPor      varchar(25)

AS
```

Y esta es la parte de mi función en donde ingreso los valores:

```
try
{

        LaConexion = new SqlConnection();
        LaConexion.ConnectionString = cadenaconexion;
        LaConexion.Open();

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("zf_Boleta_ProcesoCalculo", LaConexion);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comando.Parameters.Clear();

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroDoc", Convert.ToInt16(r.Cells[12].Value));
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDoc", r.Cells[13].Value);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorCif", r.Cells[14].Value);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorCobrar", r.Cells[16].Value);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPeriodoProcesoDetalle", Convert.ToInt16(r.Cells[17].Value)); //dato en duro

        if (qui == "M")
        {
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeriodoProceso", 'M');
        }
        else if (qui == "Q")
        {
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeriodoProceso", 'Q');
        }
        else if (qui == "D")
        {
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeriodoProceso", 'D');
        }

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mes", Convert.ToInt16(cmb_mes.Text));
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@año", Convert.ToInt16(num_anio.Value));
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCliente", Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[1].Value));
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTipoDoc", Convert.ToInt32(txt_documento.Text.Trim()));
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdValorizacionConcepto", Convert.ToInt32(txt_concepto.Text.Trim()));
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPeriodoProceso", Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[6].Value));
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreadoPor", CreadoPor);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        LaConexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (Exception o)
{
        MessageBox.Show("Hubo un problema al guardar los datos", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        MessageBox.Show(o.ToString());
}
```

He tratado con Convert.ToInt16 y 32 para el caso del @NumeroDoc que según el procedimiento es **int** pero no lo está dejando pasar. No he probado con los otros pero creo que voy a tener el mismo problema.

¿Hay otra forma de convertir los datos?

Muchas Gracias

---

Hice una prueba con:

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroDoc", int.Parse(r.Cells[12].Value.ToString()));
```

Eso está en la linea 301 de mo código y el error que me sale dice:

> System.FormatException: La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.
>
> en System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NuumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>
> en System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>
> en System.Int32.Parse(String s)
>
> en Rentasv2.Form4.btn_procesar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop etc... :

EL PROCEDIMIENTO COMPLETO ES ESTE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zf_Boleta_ProcesoCalculo]
    @NumeroDoc      int         output,
    @FechaDoc       datetime    output,
    @ValorCif       decimal(18,2)   output,
    @ValorCobrar        decimal(18,2)   output,     
    @IdPeriodoProcesoDetalle int        output,
    @PeriodoProceso     char(1),   --M=Mensual ; Q=1era.Quincena ; D=2da. Quincena
    @mes            tinyint,
    @año            smallint,
    @IdCliente      int,    
    @IdTipoDoc      int,
    @IdValorizacionConcepto int,
    @IdPeriodoProceso   int,
    @CreadoPor      varchar(25)

AS

SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET NOCOUNT ON


Declare @porcentaje decimal(18,2),@tope decimal(18,2), @fechaInicio datetime , @fechaTermino datetime 
Declare @rut integer, @Dv char(1),  @IdvalorizacionDoc integer, @registros int

BEGIN TRANSACTION

if @PeriodoProceso='M'
    Begin
    set @fechaInicio= convert(datetime,cast(@año as char(4)) + dbo.padding(0,@mes,2,'0') + '01' )
    set @fechaTermino= convert(datetime,cast(@año as char(4)) + dbo.padding(0,@mes,2,'0') + cast(datediff(dd,@fechaInicio,Dateadd(mm,1,@fechaInicio)) as char(2)) )
    End
else if @PeriodoProceso='Q'
    Begin
    set @fechaInicio= convert(datetime,cast(@año as char(4)) + dbo.padding(0,@mes,2,'0') + '01' )
    set @fechaTermino= convert(datetime,cast(@año as char(4)) + dbo.padding(0,@mes,2,'0') + '15' )
    end 
        else
    Begin
    set @fechaInicio= convert(datetime,cast(@año as char(4)) + dbo.padding(0,@mes,2,'0') + '16' )
    set @fechaTermino= convert(datetime,cast(@año as char(4)) + dbo.padding(0,@mes,2,'0') + cast(datediff(dd,@fechaInicio,Dateadd(mm,1,@fechaInicio)) as char(2))  )
    end 



Set @NumeroDoc= '9'+ dbo.padding(0,year(@fechaInicio),2,'0') + dbo.padding(0,month(@fechaInicio),2,'0')+dbo.padding(0,day(@fechaInicio),2,'0')

set @FechaDoc=@fechaTermino


-- Traer valor del concepto de calculo
select @porcentaje=porcentaje,@Tope=Tope from zf_valorizacionConcepto where idvalorizacionConcepto=@idvalorizacionConcepto
if @porcentaje is null set @porcentaje=0
if @Tope is null set @Tope=0

-- Traer Rut y Dv 
select @rut=rut,@dv=dv from zf_clientes where idCliente=@idCliente
if @rut is null set @rut=0
if @dv is null set @dv=0

set @registros=  (Select count(idBoleta) from  zf_boleta  where IdCliente=@IdCliente and idPeriodoProcesoDetalle is null )
if @registros=0 
        begin
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION            
            RETURN -10      
        end


update zf_boleta set Estado='X' where IdCliente=@IdCliente and idPeriodoProcesoDetalle is null

declare @IdBoleta int,@tipoIngreso char(1),@idTipoDocBoleta int,@sFecha datetime,@sNroBoleta int, @sLineas int, @sValorCif decimal(18,2)
declare @DocItem int , @DocValorCif decimal(18,2),@DocValorCobrar decimal(18,2),@DocIdTipoDocBoleta int,@DocsNroBoleta int,@DocsFecha datetime,@DocValorCobrarPorItem decimal(18,2)
declare @DocValorCifNotaCredito decimal(18,2),@DocValorCobrarNotaCredito decimal(18,2),@DocTipoIngreso char(1)
Declare @IdBoletaItem int
--print 'ANTES DE CURSOR'
   DECLARE CursorProceso CURSOR For Select idBoleta,
                       tipoIngreso,
                       idTipoDoc,
                       sNroBoleta,
                       sFecha,  
                       convert(int,sLineas),        
                       sValorCif                
                    from zf_boleta  
                    Where   Estado='X'  and  IdCliente=@IdCliente and idPeriodoProcesoDetalle is null
                    Order by idTipoDoc,tipoIngreso,sNroBoleta,sFecha, convert(int,sLineas)
         Open CursorProceso 
         fetch next from CursorProceso INTO @IdBoleta ,@tipoIngreso ,@idTipoDocBoleta ,@sNroBoleta,@sFecha , @sLineas , @sValorCif 

         while @@fetch_status = 0
            Begin

              Set @DocIdTipoDocBoleta=@idTipoDocBoleta
              Set @DocsNroBoleta=@sNroBoleta
              Set @DocsFecha=@sFecha    
              Set @DocTipoIngreso=@TipoIngreso
              set @DocItem=0    
              set @DocValorCif=0
              set @DocValorCobrarPorItem=0
            --  Print '@DocIdTipoDocBoleta :' +  convert(varchar(25),@DocIdTipoDocBoleta)
             -- Print '@DocsNroBoleta :' +  convert(varchar(25),@DocsNroBoleta)     
                While @@fetch_status = 0 and  @DocIdTipoDocBoleta=@idTipoDocBoleta and @DocTipoIngreso=@TipoIngreso and @DocsNroBoleta=@sNroBoleta and @DocsFecha=@sFecha
                Begin
                    set @DocItem=@DocItem+1
                    set @DocValorCif = @DocValorCif + @sValorCif    
                    set @IdBoletaItem=@IdBoleta                 
                    update zf_boleta set estado='P', porcentaje=@porcentaje where idBoleta=@IdBoleta  -- Se marca como procesados
                        fetch next from CursorProceso INTO @IdBoleta ,@tipoIngreso ,@idTipoDocBoleta ,@sNroBoleta,@sFecha , @sLineas , @sValorCif 
                end 
                -- Zona de calculo despues de sumar todos los item del documento              
                set @DocValorCobrar = case   
                            WHEN round((@DocValorCif*@porcentaje)/100,2)>=@Tope then @Tope 
                                WHEN round((@DocValorCif*@porcentaje)/100,2)<@Tope and round((@DocValorCif*@porcentaje)/100,2)>0  then round((@DocValorCif*@porcentaje)/100,2)
                            WHEN round((@DocValorCif*@porcentaje)/100,2)=0   then 0.01
                                ELSE @DocValorCif 
                            End
                set @DocValorCobrarPorItem=round((@DocValorCobrar/@DocItem),2)

            -- Asigna el valor a cobrar en el ultimo item de la boleta
            update zf_boleta set ValorCobrar = @DocValorCobrar      
            where  IdBoleta=@IdBoletaItem 

            --select idboleta,idCliente,Tipoingreso,sNroBoleta,sLineas, sValorcif,Porcentaje,ValorCobrar from zf_boleta where  IdBoleta=@IdBoletaItem  
            End     
   CLOSE CursorProceso 
   DEALLOCATE CursorProceso 



--Se obtienen los valores calculados, para insertarlos en la bases de valorizacion
--Todos lo valores excepto las notas de credito... (05-12-2007)
Select @ValorCif=sum(sValorcif),@ValorCobrar=sum(ValorCobrar)
from zf_boleta 
where  IdCliente=@IdCliente and Estado='P' and idPeriodoProcesoDetalle is null and sTipoDocumento<>'01' --cual es la nota de credito
-- si es nulo se asigna 0 cero
if @ValorCif is null set @ValorCif=0
if @ValorCobrar is null set @ValorCobrar=0


--Se obtiene los valores solo nota de credito

Select @DocValorCifNotaCredito=sum(sValorcif),@DocValorCobrarNotaCredito=sum(ValorCobrar)
from zf_boleta 
where  IdCliente=@IdCliente and Estado='P' and idPeriodoProcesoDetalle is null and sTipoDocumento='01' --falta cual es la nota de credito
-- si es nulo se asigna 0 cero
if @DocValorCifNotaCredito is null set @DocValorCifNotaCredito=0
if @DocValorCobrarNotaCredito is null set @DocValorCobrarNotaCredito=0


-- Resta la nota de credito a los valores obtenidos..
set @ValorCif=@ValorCif-@DocValorCifNotaCredito
set @ValorCobrar=@ValorCobrar-@DocValorCobrarNotaCredito



if @ValorCif is null set @ValorCif=0
if @ValorCobrar is null set @ValorCobrar=0

--Insertar en encabezado de valorizacion
INSERT
        dbo.zf_valorizacionDoc
        (
        idCliente,
        Rut,
        Dv,
        IdTipoDoc,
        NumeroDoc,
        FechaDoc,
        ValorDoc,       
        CreadoPor

        )
    VALUES
        (
        @IdCliente,
        @Rut,
        @Dv,
        @IdTipoDoc,
        @NumeroDoc,
        @FechaTermino,
        @ValorCIF,      
        @CreadoPor
        )
    IF @@ERROR != 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('R -2; Se a generado un error cuando se ejecutaba una transacción en la Base de Datos: ZonaFranca. El procedimiento que genero el error se llama : dbo.zf_Boleta_ProcesoCalculo; Registro ID : %s',10, 2, @Rut   ) WITH LOG
        RETURN -2

    END

        SET @IdvalorizacionDoc = @@IDENTITY



--insertar Valorizacion Detalle
INSERT
        dbo.zf_ValorizacionDocDetalle
        (
        IdValorizacionDoc,
        IdValorizacionConcepto,
        TipoCalculo,
        Valor,
        Porcentaje,
        Total,
        CreadoPor,
        IdConceptoGrupo
        )
    VALUES
        (
        @IdValorizacionDoc,
        @IdValorizacionConcepto,
        1,
        @ValorCIF,
        @Porcentaje,
        @ValorCobrar,
        @CreadoPor,
        20
    )

    IF @@ERROR != 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('R -3; Se a generado un error cuando se ejecutaba una transacción en la Base de Datos: ZonaFranca. El procedimiento que genero el error se llama : dbo.zf_Boleta_ProcesoCalculo; Registro ID : %s',10, 2, @IdValorizacionDoc ) WITH LOG
        RETURN -3

    END

--Inserta  en PeriodoProcesoDetalle
INSERT
        dbo.zf_PeriodoProcesoDetalle
        (
        IdPeriodoProceso,
        IdCliente,
        NroDocumento,
        FechaDoc,
        ValorCIF,
        Porcentaje,
        TotalDoc,
        CreadoPor
        )
    VALUES
        (
        @IdPeriodoProceso,
        @IdCliente,
        @NumeroDoc,
        @FechaTermino,
        @ValorCIF,
        @Porcentaje,
        @ValorCobrar,
        @CreadoPor
    )

    IF @@ERROR != 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('R 4; Se a generado un error cuando se ejecutaba una transacción en la Base de Datos: ZonaPtaArenas. El procedimiento que genero el error se llama : dbo.zf_PeriodoProcesoDetalle_Crear; Registro ID : %s',10, 2, @IdPeriodoProceso  ) WITH LOG
        RETURN -4       
    END

    SET @IdPeriodoProcesoDetalle = @@IDENTITY

update zf_boleta set IdPeriodoProcesoDetalle=@IdPeriodoProcesoDetalle
where IdCliente=@IdCliente and Estado='P' and IdPeriodoProcesoDetalle is null



COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Una pregunta para que los declaras como OutPut? si al final no los estas devolviendo

Comment: Ya probaste con **`int.Parse(r.Cells[12].Value);`** ???

Comment: @EdgarVazquez si los ocupo pero en otra función en donde los paso a in informe con crystal report

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO voy a probar y te aviso, gracias

Comment: Pero más parece un error acerca de lo que dice @EdgarVazquez, cuando declaras el parámetro como `OUTPUT` no deberías mandárselo al sp

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos el sp de forma completa para ver que tratas de hacer? es que el error pienso que es por eso del OUTPUT cuando lo tienes de esa forma es para que lo recuperes posteriormente

Comment: @EdgarVazquez ok, voy a agregar el procedimiento completo, aunque te aviso que es grande el código jajaja

Comment: Veo que el campo solo por hablar de uno @NumeroDoc no es necesario mandarlo ya que se calcula solo en esta parte Set @NumeroDoc= '9'+ dbo.padding(0,year(@fechaInicio),2,'0') + dbo.padding(0,month(@fechaInicio),2,'0')+dbo.padding(0,day(@fechaInicio),2,'0'), entonces para que estas tratando de mandarlo? y si solo quisieras recuperar el valor tendrias que hacer algo como cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; Para que al final pudieras recuperarlo

Comment: Asi que lo que deberias de hacer es recuperarlos como te dije y los demas si mandarlos ya que esos si son necesarios pero todos los que son tipo OUTPUT si te das cuenta no son necesario mandarlo ya que se calculan en el momento

Comment: @EdgarVazquez ok, bueno de partida recien estoy empezando con los procedimientos almacenados y me pusieron a trabajar con uno ya creado. voy a hacer lo que dices, no voy a tomar en cuenta los primeros 5 que dices que son OUTPUT, pero para el caso del mes, que si es requerido, como convierto ese dato?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumeroDoc", SqlDbType.int);
        cmd.Parameters["@NumeroDoc"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
Esto para los que sean OUTPUT poniendo el tipo de cada uno correspondiente, y los que sean obligatorios esta bien como lo haces solo verifica que sean los datos correctos, es decir si espera un INT que sea un INT y si es un NVARCHAR sea un string, creo que lo demas lo tienes bien, prueba solo con lo de los OUTPUT

Comment: ok. muchas gracias

Comment: Funciono? asi como te dije o probaras aun

Comment: probé lo que me dijiste y funciona, se cae en algunas variables pero por lo que estoy viendo es porque las saca de otro lado, o sea, las tengo que generar antes y después mandarlas. así que estoy con eso. funcionó

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda No olvides marcar la respuesta de Edgar como valida para que sea de ayuda para otros usuarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo el detalle lo tienes en que estas tratando de mandar las variables de tipo OUTPUT y esas variables se ponen de otro modo.

Aqui te muestro como quedaria el primero.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumeroDoc", SqlDbType.int); //En SqlDbType se pone el dato que sea, si fuera un NVARCHAR se pondria cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumeroDoc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30); donde esta el 30 seria el valor del texto
cmd.Parameters["@NumeroDoc"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; //Aqui le indicamos que es de tipo OutPut.
```

Ahora los demas como lo tienes esta bien.

Es decir este por ejemplo.

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mes", Convert.ToInt16(cmb_mes.Text));
```

Asi es como se mandan solo verifica que la variable @Mes sea un INT en este caso.

Te dejo algo de información en los siguientes enlaces

En este puedes encontrar los equivalentes de datos para cuando no sepas cuando usar un Int32 o un Int16 etc...

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes

En este puedes ver tambien el uso de parametros de tipo OUTPUT

> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/539269/outputplusparameterplusinplusstoredplusprocedurepl

Saludos